# Помогите очистить значение Комбобокса

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть вот такое чудо:

```
void AddIntToCombobox(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox f, int a) // f поступающий combobox, a поступающая переменная 
{
    if (!f.Items.Contains(a)) // проверяю если нету такого элемента
       f.Items.Add(a); // добавить
}
```

А вот как сделать так, если такой элемент в комбобоксе есть, а в int a; он не поступил то его из комбобокса удалить, то есть: 
Есть в комбобоксе вот такие строки или они остались от предыдущего запроса(1,2,3,4,5 ну и т.д) а в int a поступили вот такие строки (1,3,5)
То нужно удалить из комбобокса 2 и 4 вот как это можно сделать, помогите пожалуйста)

```
void ss()
{
    AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, 1); //первый параметр это какой комбобокс
    AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, 3);// второй это какое значение
    AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, 5);
}
```

Comment: И как вы в `int` запихнёте несколько значений (1,3,5)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ого, какой у вас ровненький счет :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov === А вы увидели что сверху приходит параметр ?
Я говорил что приходят вот такие параметры(1,3,5)...
я вызываю его внизу  
AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, 1); AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, 3); AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, 5);

Comment: Например, добавьте в класс поле `private List<int> _listInts = new List<int>();` ну и в этом методе добавляете в него ваши пришедшие `int a`, затем сравнивайте содержимое `listInts`  с `f.items`.

Comment: @ Bulson Извините конечно, но можете привести пример этого, а то чет уже ничего не соображаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, как то так

```
void AddIntToCombobox(ComboBox f, params int[] a) // f поступающий combobox, a поступающая переменная 
{
    foreach (var item in a)
        if (!f.Items.Contains(item)) // проверяю если нету такого элемента
            f.Items.Add(item); // добавить

    var comboItems = f.Items.OfType<int>().ToArray();
    foreach (var item in comboItems)
        if (!a.Contains(item)) // проверяю если нету такого элемента
            f.Items.Remove(item); // удалить
}
```

Вызвать можно так

```
var combo = new ComboBox();
AddIntToCombobox(combo, 1, 2, 3);
```

UPD

Можно заменить вот это

```
foreach (var i in g) { 
    AddIntToCombobox(comboBox1, i.Numbers); 
    AddIntToCombobox(comboBox1, i.Count); 
    AddIntToCombobox(comboBox1, i.Cell); 
    AddIntToCombobox(comboBox2, i.Long); 
    AddIntToCombobox(comboBox2, i.RAID); 
}
```

на

```
AddIntToCombobox(comboBox1, g.SelectMany(x => new[] {x.Numbers, x.Count, x.Cell}).ToArray());
AddIntToCombobox(comboBox2, g.SelectMany(x => new[] {x.Long, x.RAID}).ToArray());
```

Comment: Извините а если я это всё делаю через foreach как тогда быть ?
 
            foreach (var i in g)
            {
                AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, i.Numbers);
                AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, i.Count);
                AddStringToCombobox(comboBox1, i.Cell);
                AddStringToCombobox(comboBox2, iLong);
                AddStringToCombobox(comboBox2, i.RAID);
            }

Comment: @user289178 обновил ответ

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за `params`. Не знал, что так можно ;-)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо вам огромное))